# Converting a 24v bldc to 12v

Tags: power, brushless-dc-motor, 12v, 24v

So I have been designing a brushless motor and the circuit that drives it is based off of this Texas Instruments one [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidr561/tidr561.pdf). The only problem is that this circuit runs off a minimum of 24v. I would like to use 12v, but I wasn't sure of the best way to go about doing this. The motor pre-driver (DRV8308) will work with 12v.

EDIT: Can someone at least explain to me why it is 24v minimum on the circuit i linked?

Comment: Where does it say 24V minimum? The driver chip works on 12V and the MOSFETs won't complain either...

Comment: On the page on which I found the schematic. http://www.ti.com/tool/tida-00197

Comment: Well, all the chips work at 12V, I really wonder why they specced a minimum of 24V! You could ask them... IMO it should work...

Comment: Yeah maybe its because the RPM and/or torque would be reduced (lower voltage into the coils)